# Passing an array of Struct to a sorting function in C

Tags: arrays, c, struct

I'm trying to pass an array of `struct` to a function that works with it and modify its content.  I've read many articles but I still cannot find what I need.

I need to pass this array of `struct` to a function and work with the values of this array, and the modifications need to be *global* modifications.

Here, I'm actually sorting the values of the areas of this structure; the program gives me this warning and crashes:

> warning: passing argument 1 of 'insersort' from incompatible pointer
> type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]|

```
struct rectangle{
    char name[MAXC];
    float x;
    float y;
    float area;
    float perimeter;
};

void insersort(struct rectangle *rect[],int k)
{
    int i,j;
    float x;
    for(i=1;i<k;i++)
    {
        x=rect[i]->area;
        j=i-1;
        while(j>=0 && x<rect[j]->area)
        {
            rect[j+1]->area=rect[j]->area;
            j--;
        }
        rect[j]->area=x;
    }
    return;
}
.....
```

I call the function like so:

```
struct rectangle rect[MAX];
insersort(rect,k);
```

Comment: Too much indirection. Define the first function argument either as `struct rectangle rect[]` or as `struct rectangle *rect` but not both. Your `struct rectangle *rect[]` is an array of pointers.

Comment: ^^^^^ e.g. in `insersort`, the parameter should be `struct rectangle rect[]` and all `rect[n]->` should be changed to `rect[n].`

Answer (score 1):

You wrote

```
void insersort(struct rectangle *rect[],int k)
```

and the body of insertof is written as though you meant

```
void insersort(struct rectangle (*rect)[],int k)
```

that is, array of pointer to `rect`

but you probably meant to write it as

```
void insersort(struct rectangle rect[],int k)
```

and not use `->` inside `insertof`

Comment: How is it possible to use for example rect[i].area inside the function, I mean i need to work with pointers since the struct is passed by reference, If I pass the struct as  void insersort(struct rectangle rect[],int k) is it passed by reference ? since there is no '*' specified in the parameter of the function, isn't the function working on a copy of it ? tried many and many modifications to the program and none worked. Thanks.

Comment: @Big-D: Because an array is always passed by reference.

Comment: Thanks, now it works, I was sure to have to use '->' in function to work with an array struct but i was wrong.